# ¿Como utilizar un valor por defecto al modelo de un segment en ionic 2?

Tags: angular, ionic, ionic2

Estoy usando el ejemplo de segment de la documentación de ionic. en el ejemplo hay dos `*ngSwitchCase` que son estos `*ngSwitchCase="'puppies'"` y  `*ngSwitchCase="'kittens'"`, lo que quiero lograr es que por defecto el valor sea puppies.

```
<div padding>
  <ion-segment [(ngModel)]="pet">
    <ion-segment-button value="kittens">
      Kittens
    </ion-segment-button>
    <ion-segment-button value="puppies">
      Puppies
    </ion-segment-button>
  </ion-segment>
</div>

<div [ngSwitch]="pet">
  <ion-list *ngSwitchCase="'puppies'">
    <ion-item>
      <ion-thumbnail item-start>
        <img src="img/thumbnail-puppy-1.jpg">
      </ion-thumbnail>
      <h2>Ruby</h2>
    </ion-item>
    ...
  </ion-list>

  <ion-list *ngSwitchCase="'kittens'">
    <ion-item>
      <ion-thumbnail item-start>
        <img src="img/thumbnail-kitten-1.jpg">
      </ion-thumbnail>
      <h2>Luna</h2>
    </ion-item>
    ...
  </ion-list>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dado que la variable que se usa para determinar el segment visible es `pet` (`<ion-segment [(ngModel)]="pet">...</ion-segment>`) para mostrar por defecto la sección de `puppies` lo único que tenes que hacer es asignarle dicho valor a la variable en el componente de la página:

```
constructor(...) {
  this.pet = 'puppies';
}
```

De esa forma ese segmento va a ser el seleccionado por defecto. Si lo quisieras cambiar desde el código, solo reemplaza el valor de esa variable por el de alguno de los demás segmentos, por ejemplo:

```
public seleccionarOtroSegment(): void {
  this.pet = 'kittens';
}
```